# Mozilla Rendering. First LI element is floating to the right

Tags: css, firefox, wordpress-theming

Within the confines of a Wordpress plugin (and a client approved graphic designer layout), I have created and am working on styling a form. But, in Firefox, in the second list of selection in the left column, the first list item is oddly hanging out to the right http://litecheck.mscreativelabs.com/contact/ . It is only doing this in Firefox. I have been digging through the styles for a while and can't find what is doing this.

Comment: Cant find what you mean? In FF5 it looks fine but in IE9, there is overlapping - FF = http://i55.tinypic.com/332qjw3.jpg and IE9 = http://i52.tinypic.com/sec2lt.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I am going to tackle IE next (I hate having to use absolute position), but I can't talk the client out of the two column thing now. It is actually hiding in FF5, you'll have to find the first li within that last in the code.

Comment: Can you atleast give the id or class of the ul and li so I can look it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a clear:left to the ul, or to li.gchoice_2_1